# Visual C++ not allowing iostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I just started C++ I am reading the ebook Starting out with C++ 7th edition. I  copied the code from the book and put it into Visual, under new project w32 console app with precompiled headers. Well When I use the iostream in the preprocessor directive line i get.. I searched around and do not understand why the iostream won't work, any help?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: dd, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp 1>  dd.cpp 1>c:\documents and settings\leon\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dd\dd\dd.cpp(24): fatal error
C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header.
Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

```
    1 // This program calculates the user's pay.
    2 #include <iostream>
    3 using namespace std;
    4
    5 int main()
    6 {
    7 double hours, rate, pay;
    8
    9 // Get the number of hours worked.
    10 cout << "How many hours did you work? ";
    11 cin >> hours;
    12
    13 // Get the hourly pay rate.
    14 cout << "How much do you get paid per hour? ";
    15 cin >> rate;
    16
    17 // Calculate the pay.
    18 pay = hours * rate;
    19
    20 // Display the pay.
    21 cout << "You have earned $" << pay << endl;
    22 return 0;
    23 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not because of `iostream`, but because you forgot to include `stdafx.h`.

The error is pretty clear on that. If you build projects with precompile headers, you have to include `stdafx.h` at the beginning of your implementation files.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual C++, project can use what is called "pre-compiled headers". This is a technique to help speed up building of the project. For this to work you need to `#include` the file "stdafx.h" as the first thing you do in the source file.

So add this line before the inclusion of iostream:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

When you build again it should work.

Comment: I just did that and now I am getting  missing function header.

Comment: @user1211008 Did you add the new line _before_ you include iostream? It must always be the first non-comment line in the source files. You might also try to rebuild the solution.

Comment: I found it. Misplaced ; after int main()

Comment: Got it working, for a bit, I just wanted to see if I could even start on a textbook example. Thank you for the help. Now to solve this issue,, googling..Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: okay for some reason the pdb files were not checked in the debug options... just checked them and hit debug for some reason C++ is trying to load avast snxhk.dll and cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

Include the following header ..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
```

(remove .h extension - VS2010 seems to not find the header file with that file extension)?

Answer (score -1):

When you create the new project, instead of selecting "w32 console app", select "Empty Project", then create a new CPP file, and the code should work!

Comment: I did that and now it cant find the specified file hours.exe, after I debug the source code.

Comment: I understand why it is saying that but I thought when you, debug it creates a .exe?